# What does the GGGGotate & lol mean in the following code

Tags: python

```
def GGGGotate(lol):
    bit = lol << 1
    movebit = bit & 255
    if (lol > 127):
```

I tried google and apparently the only thing GGGGotate brings me to is a compiler with what looks like an encryption code.

Comment: Is a function definition. It doesn't mean anything, you could choose any other name.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is a [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)*:

```py
def GGGGotate(lol):
    ...
```

- `def` means define a function
- `GGGGotate` is the name of the function
- `lol` is its unique argument (contained in the parentheses)

* the definition is incomplete as the final if block has no body

Comment: Thank you. I am new to python and I was overthinking it.